# An unusual co-ordinate geometry question

Tags: analytic-geometry, conic-sections

I have have come across an unusual co-ordinate geometry question:

**Line** $x^2+y^2+axy=0, a \in \Re$ cuts an ellipse $x^2+4y^2=4$ at two points A and B. Find the locus of points of intersection of the tangents drawn at A and B.

In here, a pair of family of lines passing through origin has been referred to as a line! Also a pair of lines would cut the ellipse at **four** points and not at two!!

I may come back. Your comment/suggestion/solution is welcome.

**EDIT:** The suggested solution in the nondescript reference that I came across asks  to take the point $(h,k)$ and write the equation of the chord of contact of the ellipse as $hx+4ky=4$, next homogenize it with the ellipse as $$x^2+4y^2=4\left(\frac{hx+4ky}{4}\right)^2$$ the combined equation of OA and OB as  $$(1-h^2/4)x^2+(4-4k^2)y^2-2hkxy=0.....(*)$$
and compare it with another combined equation of OA and OB namely $x^2+y^2+axy=0$ to get a connection between $h$ and $k$ to get the desired locus one gets: $1-h^2/4=4-4k^2$. Hence the required locus is
$$x^2-16y^2+12=0.$$

Comment: Where did you find his question? These are obviously not lines. If your question was "how to solve it?", please first present what you tried.

Comment: All the times you cannot give a reference also because it wont be acessessible to you. Next, the language of the question is it self so disturbing. Some funny solution was given I am trying to get it, may put it in an EDIT. But  quick and null response of yours is not at all understandable!  You are unnecessarily trespassing here.

Comment: I am not sure to understand your whole comment (there seems to be a barrier of language, on both sides). I was as puzzled as you by the obvious mistake, that is why was curious where you found this text, even if I have no access to it. As for the rest of my comment, it simply recalled the general rule on MSE, because the tone of the last paragraph shocked me. And it was a conditional, because the aim of this post was (and still is) unclear to me.

Comment: The two curves described by $x^2+y^2+axy=0$ are explicitly given by $$
y=\frac{-a\pm\sqrt{a^2-4}}{2}x\,.
$$ The rest of the exercise is straightforward. It does not matter how we call those curves, even though they are obviously straight lines. It also does not matter if we take advantage of symmetry and ignore the other pair of points where they intersect the ellipse. I will surely not come back. :)

Comment: Thanks, yes, I think this is how this question would make sense.

Answer (score 1):

Interestingly, the pole of a line passing through the center of a circle or conic either doesn't exist or it is found at infinity. In other words, the tangents at the end points of these lines are parallel. So as also pointed by @Kurt G. we can ignore the other two ends of pair of lines and work out the locus of point of intersection of tangents put of points A and B. Let the equation of lines be $y=mx$ and $y=x/m$.

The points of intersection of these lines with the given ellipse $x^2+4y^2=4$
are $$A\left(\frac{1}{2\sqrt{1+4m^2}},\frac{2m}{\sqrt{1+4m^2}}\right);\quad B\left(\frac{m}{2\sqrt{4+m^2}},\frac{2}{\sqrt{4+m^2}}\right).$$
Equations of tangents on the ellipse at these point are
$$x+4my=2\sqrt{1+4m^2}; \quad mx+4y=2\sqrt{4+m^2}$$
The point of intersection C of these two tangents is found to be
$$C=(x,y)= \left(2\frac{\sqrt{1+4m^2}-m\sqrt{4+m^2}}{2(m^2-1)},\frac{\sqrt{4+m^2}-m\sqrt{1+4m^2}}{2(m^2-1)}\right).$$
Thankfully, 'Eliminate' command helps in eliminaion the eliminant is the required locus: $$x^2-16y^2+12=0,$$
which is exactly the same as obtained in the EDIT part of my problem proposal in the post.